# How to compute total of all rows inside table with infinite loop came from phpmyadmin (Dec 23, 2019)

Tags: php, jquery, sql

Help I have a problem when displaying the total of the datas came from phpmyadmin,

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "
     <tr>
        <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic1']}</td>
        <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic2']}</td>
        <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic3']}</td>
        <td class='total'> /3</td>
        </tr>";
}
```

What could I add to make the last "td" with a value of 'total' compute the the value inside 
logic1,2,3??? in my database I already have 10 records of it, and I want them to be total 
separately. Any comment would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So, you want a sum of logic1,2,3?

Comment: Just a note - phpmyadmin is just a tool to query and manage the database - this is most likely a MySQL database you are using.  Sometimes getting the wrong terminology can make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a total `per-row` so you could try like below or alternatively do the sum in the database and include that in the recordset as well as the other fields.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $total=0;
    for( $i=1; $i<=3; $i++ )$total += $row["logic{$i}"];

    echo "
    <tr>
        <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic1']}</td>
        <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic2']}</td>
        <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic3']}</td>
        <td class='total'>{$total}/3</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

with a small modification you can keep a rolling total for all records

```
$sumtotal=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $total=0;
    for( $i=1; $i<=3; $i++ )$total += $row["logic{$i}"];

    $sumtotal+=$total;

    echo "
    <tr>
        <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic1']}</td>
        <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic2']}</td>
        <td class='count-me'>{$row['logic3']}</td>
        <td class='total'>{$total}/3</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

Or calculate `per-row` in the database

```
select a,b,c,(a+b+c) as total from `table`
```